# How to "communicate" between components in Angular?

Tags: angular, components

How to exchange data between components in Angular?

For instance, communicating between parent and child components or between siblings.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. Are you trying to trying to do rpc, message passing or just share variables?

Answer (score 19):

If you are trying to communicate from a parent component to a child component, this is pretty clearly described using @Input and EventEmitters with @Output in the angular docs.

[Angular 2 component interaction](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

As for communication across siblings, I posted an answer in a similar question that might help with the issue of sharing data across sibling components.  Currently, i think the shared service method is the most efficient.

[angular-2-sibling-component-communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication)

Comment: I found the answer useful and upvoted it, but then saw in the other page that its mainly relevant up to Angular 2: Alex J's answer is good but it no longer works with current Angular 4 as of July, 2017

Answer (score 19):

**Using a service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  public _subject = new Subject<object>();
  public event = this._subject.asObservable();

  public publish(data: any) {
    this._subject.next(data);
  }
}
```

and you can publish event-like messages like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(
    public appState: AppState
  ) {
    appState.publish({data: 'some data'});
  }
}
```

and you can subscribe to these events:

```
export class HomeComponent {
  constructor(
    public appState: AppState
  ) {
    appState.event.subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data); // {data: 'some data'}
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: If anyone looking for more generic approach based on share service and observable, can check out this article https://codewithlogic.wordpress.com/2020/04/18/communication-among-nested-components-in-angular/

Answer (score 12):

1. @Input and @Output

   If there are multipart components
   you can use @Input and @Output to exchange data.
   Document : https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

   example: https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/component-interaction/eplnkr.html
2. Dependency Injection

   you can store the data in Service, and then inject Service into the component which you want. such as "user.server.ts" in the example:

   https://angular.io/generated/live-examples/dependency-injection/eplnkr.html

Comment: second link is broken, please fix it if possible

Answer (score 4):

You will need to use dependency injection. Here is a small example:
https://github.com/gdi2290/angular2do/blob/gh-pages/app/components/todo-item/todo-item.js

Answer (score 1):

[using DataService stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-br2zzl)

**sender.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {dataService} from './dataservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  //name = 'Angular';
  constructor(private SVC: dataService ){

  }
  sender(){
    this.SVC.name="sender"
    console.log("sending this string:    "+this.SVC.name)
  }

}
```

**dataservice.ts**

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

    @Injectable()
    export class dataService {
    name=""
      constructor() { }
    }
```

**receiver.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {dataService} from '../dataservice.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-recieved',
  templateUrl: './recieved.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./recieved.component.css']
})
export class RecievedComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataservice: dataService ){

  }
  ngOnInit() { 
  }
print(){
  console.log("recieved:    " +this.dataservice.name)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By using any of the following methods we can connect 2 components.

1. using @input()
2. using @output()
3. using services.
4. parent component calling viewchild.
5. parent interacting with child using a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is **Events** API in angular which can do it for you.

[Click here for more details on Events.](https://angular.io/api/router/Event)

Below is a quick example I am currently using in my project. Hope it helps someone in need.

> import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

Usage :

```
  constructor(public events: Events) {
        /*=========================================================
        =  Keep this block in any component you want to receive event response to            =
        ==========================================================*/
        // Event Handlers
        events.subscribe('menu:opened', () => {
            // your action here
            console.log('menu:opened');
        });
        events.subscribe('menu:closed', () => {
            // your action here
            console.log('menu:closed');
        });
    }

    /*=====================================================
    = Call these on respective events - I used them for Menu open/Close          =
    ======================================================*/

    menuClosed() {
        // Event Invoke
        this.events.publish('menu:closed', '');
    }
    menuOpened() {
        // Event Invoke
        this.events.publish('menu:opened', '');
    }

  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Inter component communication can be achieved in AngularJS. In AngularJS we have something called as **require** property which needs to be mapped in the component. Follow the example below which will access the function **addPane(parameter)** of the component **myTabs** from the component **myPane**: -

Project structure:

HTML

1. index.html
2. my-tabs.html
3. my-pane.html

JS

1. script.js

**script.js**

```js
angular.module('docsTabsExample', [])
    .component('myTabs', {
      transclude: true,
      controller: function MyTabsController() {
        var panes = this.panes = [];
        this.select = function(pane) {
          angular.forEach(panes, function(pane) {
            pane.selected = false;
          });
          pane.selected = true;
        };
        this.addPane = function(pane) {
          if (panes.length === 0) {
            this.select(pane);
          }
          panes.push(pane);
        };
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-tabs.html'
    })
    .component('myPane', {
      transclude: true,
      require: {          //This property will be used to map other component
        tabsCtrl: '^myTabs' // Add ^ symbol before the component name which you want to map.
      },
      bindings: {
        title: '@'
      },
      controller: function() {
        this.$onInit = function() {
          this.tabsCtrl.addPane(this);  //Calling the function addPane from other component.
          console.log(this);
        };
      },
      templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'
    });
```

**index.html**

```html
<my-tabs>
  <my-pane title="Hello">
    <h4>Hello</h4>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </my-pane>
  <my-pane title="World">
    <h4>World</h4>
    <em>Mauris elementum elementum enim at suscipit.</em>
    <p><a href ng-click="i = i + 1">counter: {{i || 0}}</a></p>
  </my-pane>
</my-tabs>
```

**my-tabs.html**

```html
<div class="tabbable">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li ng-repeat="pane in $ctrl.panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">
      <a href="" ng-click="$ctrl.select(pane)">{{pane.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content" ng-transclude></div>
</div>
```

**my-pane.html**

```html
<div class="tab-pane" ng-show="$ctrl.selected" ng-transclude></div>
```

Code snippet : https://plnkr.co/edit/diQjxq7D0xXTqPunBWVE?p=preview

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication

Hope this helps :)