# Angular 2 Sibling Component Communication

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a ListComponent.  When an item is clicked in ListComponent, the details of that item should be shown in DetailComponent.  Both are on the screen at the same time, so there's no routing involved.

How do I tell DetailComponent what item in ListComponent was clicked?

I've considered emitting an event up to the parent (AppComponent), and have the parent set the selectedItem.id on DetailComponent with an @Input.  Or I could use a shared service with observable subscriptions.

---

**EDIT:** Setting the selected item via event + @Input doesn't trigger the DetailComponent, though, in case I were to need to execute additional code.  So I'm not sure this is an acceptable solution.

---

But both of these methods seem far more complex than the Angular 1 way of doing things which was either through $rootScope.$broadcast or $scope.$parent.$broadcast.

With everything in Angular 2 being a component, I'm surprised there's not more information out there about component communication.

Is there another/more straightforward way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did u found any way for sibling data sharing ? I need it as observable..

Answer (score 67):

**Updated to rc.4:**
When trying to get data passed between sibling components in angular 2, The simplest way right now (angular.rc.4) is to take advantage of angular2's hierarchal dependency injection and create a shared service.

Here would be the service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    dataArray: string[] = [];

    insertData(data: string){
        this.dataArray.unshift(data);
    }
}
```

Now, here would be the PARENT component

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from './shared.service';
import {ChildComponent} from './child.component';
import {ChildSiblingComponent} from './child-sibling.component';
@Component({
    selector: 'parent-component',
    template: `
        <h1>Parent</h1>
        <div>
            <child-component></child-component>
            <child-sibling-component></child-sibling-component>
        </div>
    `,
    providers: [SharedService],
    directives: [ChildComponent, ChildSiblingComponent]
})
export class parentComponent{

}
```

and its two children

child 1

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {SharedService} from './shared.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'child-component',
    template: `
        <h1>I am a child</h1>
        <div>
            <ul *ngFor="#data in data">
                <li>{{data}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    `
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit{
    data: string[] = [];
    constructor(
        private _sharedService: SharedService) { }
    ngOnInit():any {
        this.data = this._sharedService.dataArray;
    }
}
```

child 2 (It's sibling)

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {SharedService} from './shared.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'child-sibling-component',
    template: `
        <h1>I am a child</h1>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="data"/>
        <button (click)="addData()"></button>
    `
})
export class ChildSiblingComponent{
    data: string = 'Testing data';
    constructor(
        private _sharedService: SharedService){}
    addData(){
        this._sharedService.insertData(this.data);
        this.data = '';
    }
}
```

NOW: Things to take note of when using this method.

1. Only include the service provider for the shared service in the PARENT component and NOT the children.
2. You still have to include constructors and import the service in the children
3. This answer was originally answered for an early angular 2 beta version. All that has changed though are the import statements, so that is all you need to update if you used the original version by chance.

Comment: Thanks, But any idea why its not working when we add the service as providers ?? i struggled with this for a while and didn't work until i removed the providers

Comment: Is this still valid for angular-rc1?

Comment: I don't believe this notifies the sibling that something has updated in the shared service, though.  If child-component1 does something that child-component2 needs to respond to, this method doesn't handle that.

I believe the way around that is with observables?

Comment: @Sufyan: I'm going to guess that adding the provider fields to the children causes Angular to create new private instances for each one. When you do not add them, they use the parent's "singleton" instance.

Comment: This is great! Nice easy way to pass data (hopefully its the correct way to handle it) @Sergio, can confirm this works currently, but am still looking to see if its the official way to do this. Anyone confirm

Comment: Looks like this is not working anymore with the latest updates

Comment: @SufyanJabr I updated it to the latest version. Sorry for the delay. Nothing much has changed, though.

Comment: @AlexJ what is that `directives: [ChildComponent, ChildSiblingComponent]` code in Component decorator on the Parent model? I can't find that in angular.io documentation. Thanks

Comment: if the shared service is the parent component, then how come the child component can directly access the parent component. It does not make sense here

Comment: This is outdated. `directives` are no longer declared in the component.

Comment: According to [40538634](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40538681/6287237), directives should outright be removed from component decorator.

Answer (score 29):

In case of 2 different components (not nested components, parent\child\grandchild ) I suggest you this:

> MissionService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()

export class MissionService {
  // Observable string sources
  private missionAnnouncedSource = new Subject<string>();
  private missionConfirmedSource = new Subject<string>();
  // Observable string streams
  missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
  missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();
  // Service message commands
  announceMission(mission: string) {
    this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
  }
  confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
    this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
  }

}
```

> AstronautComponent:

```
import { Component, Input, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { MissionService } from './mission.service';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-astronaut',
  template: `
    <p>
      {{astronaut}}: <strong>{{mission}}</strong>
      <button
        (click)="confirm()"
        [disabled]="!announced || confirmed">
        Confirm
      </button>
    </p>
  `
})
export class AstronautComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @Input() astronaut: string;
  mission = '<no mission announced>';
  confirmed = false;
  announced = false;
  subscription: Subscription;
  constructor(private missionService: MissionService) {
    this.subscription = missionService.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(
      mission => {
        this.mission = mission;
        this.announced = true;
        this.confirmed = false;
    });
  }
  confirm() {
    this.confirmed = true;
    this.missionService.confirmMission(this.astronaut);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

> Source: [Parent and children communicate via a service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: Would like you to add some terminology to this answer. I believe it to fall in line with RxJS, Observable pattern, etc.. not entirely sure, but adding descriptions to some of this would be beneficial for people (like myself).

Comment: EventEmitters.emit(value) just calls super.next(value). Why not use EventEmitters and pass that class to a child? public missionAnnounced; public missionAnnoucedChange = new EventEmitter<any>(/* true for async if you get data changed errors */); <some-component [(missionAnnounced)]="missionAnnouced" [missionAnnouncedSiblingOrSelfChange]="missionAnnounceChange". When you subscribe to this eventEmitter, you need to manually unsubscribe in destructor.

Answer (score 15):

One way to do this is using a [shared service](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).

However I find the following
solution much simpler, it allows to share data between 2 siblings.(I tested this only on **Angular 5**)

**In you parent component template:**

```
<!-- Assigns "AppSibling1Component" instance to variable "data" -->
<app-sibling1 #data></app-sibling1>
<!-- Passes the variable "data" to AppSibling2Component instance -->
<app-sibling2 [data]="data"></app-sibling2>
```

**app-sibling2.component.ts**

```
import { AppSibling1Component } from '../app-sibling1/app-sibling1.component';
...

export class AppSibling2Component {
   ...
   @Input() data: AppSibling1Component;
   ...
}
```

Comment: Isn't this opposing the idea of loose coupling and thus of components?

Comment: Anyone has any idea whether this is a clean or dirty way to it?
It seems a lot simpler for sharing data in one direction, for example only from sibiling1 to sibiling2, but not the other way around

Comment: @Robin Sometimes you're components cannnot be loosly coupled. For example in the case one component should control another component and it is a nice feature that you can decide in the template which component should talk to another component. A service won't work if you want to wire up components. For example a component provides a user interface to select displayed columns and another component is responsible for rendering a list, but you want to reuse both components in multiple templates.

Comment: I agree with @Sebi2020. Services are global state. You can have lingering state. And we all know why global state is frowned upon.

Answer (score 9):

There is a discussion about it here.

https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2663

Alex J's answer is good but it no longer works with current Angular 4 as of July, 2017.

And this plunker link would demonstrate how to communicate between siblings using shared service and observable.

https://embed.plnkr.co/P8xCEwSKgcOg07pwDrlO/

Answer (score 8):

A directive can make sense in certain situations to 'connect' components. In fact the things being connected don't even need to be full components, and sometimes it's more lightweight and actually simpler if they aren't.

For example I've got a `Youtube Player` component (wrapping Youtube API) and I wanted some controller buttons for it. The only reason the buttons aren't part of my main component is that they're located elsewhere in the DOM.

In this case it's really just an 'extension' component that will only ever be of use with the 'parent' component. I say 'parent', but in the DOM it is a sibling - so call it what you will.

Like I said it doesn't even need to be a full component, in my case it's just a `<button>` (but it could be a component).

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[ytPlayerPlayButton]'
})
export class YoutubePlayerPlayButtonDirective {

    _player: YoutubePlayerComponent; 

    @Input('ytPlayerVideo')
    private set player(value: YoutubePlayerComponent) {
       this._player = value;    
    }

    @HostListener('click') click() {
        this._player.play();
    }

   constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
       // the button itself
   }
}
```

In the HTML for `ProductPage.component`, where `youtube-player` is obviously my component that wraps the Youtube API.

```
<youtube-player #technologyVideo videoId='NuU74nesR5A'></youtube-player>

... lots more DOM ...

<button class="play-button"        
        ytPlayerPlayButton
        [ytPlayerVideo]="technologyVideo">Play</button>
```

The directive hooks everything up for me, and I don't have to declare the (click) event in the HTML.

So the directive can nicely connect to the video player without having to involve `ProductPage` as a mediator.

This is the first time I've actually done this, so not yet sure how scalable it might be for much more complex situations. For this though I'm happy and it leaves my HTML simple and responsibilities of everything distinct.

Comment: One of the most important angular concepts to understand is that a component is just a directive with a template. Once you really appreciate what this means then directives aren't quite so scary - and you'll realize you can apply them to any element to attach behavior to it.

Comment: I've tried this but I get a duplicate identifier error for the equivalent of `player`. If I leave off the first mention of player I get a rangeError. I'm stumped as to how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @KatharineOsborne Looks like in my actual code I use `_player` for the private field that represents the player, so yes you would get an error if you copied this exactly. Will update. Sorry!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver What do you do if you have a component (not a single button) which contains multiple buttons. For example play, pause, stop rewind, forward etc. ?

Answer (score 6):

Shared service is a good solution for this issue. If you want to store some activity information too, you can add Shared Service to your main modules (app.module) provider list.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        SharedService,
        ...
    ]
});
```

Then you can directly provide it to your components,

```
constructor(private sharedService: SharedService)
```

With Shared Service you can either use functions or you can create a Subject to update multiple places at once.

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {
    public clickedItemInformation: Subject<string> = new Subject(); 
}
```

In your list component you can publish clicked item information,

```
this.sharedService.clikedItemInformation.next("something");
```

and then you can fetch this information at your detail component:

```
this.sharedService.clikedItemInformation.subscribe((information) => {
    // do something
});
```

Obviously, the data that list component shares can be anything. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the most straight forward (aka terse) example of this concept of a shared service, and should really by upvoted to increase its visibility, since there is no accepted answer.

Comment: This shares data through global scope (services). Navigation can have lingering state.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set up the parent-child relationship between your components. The problem is that you might simply inject the child components in the constructor of the parent component and store it in a local variable.
Instead, you should declare the child components in your parent component by using the `@ViewChild` property declarator.
This is how your parent component should look like:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { DetailComponent } from './detail.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  template: '<list-component></list-component><detail-component></detail-component>',
  directives: [ListComponent, DetailComponent]
})
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ListComponent) listComponent:ListComponent;
  @ViewChild(DetailComponent) detailComponent: DetailComponent;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // afther this point the children are set, so you can use them
    this.detailComponent.doSomething();
  }
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-var.html

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#parent-to-view-child

Beware, the child component will not be available in the constructor of the parent component, just after the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook is called. To catch this hook simple implement the `AfterViewInit` interface in you parent class the same way you would do with `OnInit`.

But, there are other property declarators as explained in this blog note:
http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/01/23/angular2-viewchildren-contentchildren-difference-viewproviders/

Answer (score 4):

Here is simple practical explanation:Simply explained [here](https://musttoknows.com/angular-4-angular-5-communicate-two-components-using-observable-subject/)

In call.service.ts

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class CallService {
 private subject = new Subject<any>();

 sendClickCall(message: string) {
    this.subject.next({ text: message });
 }

 getClickCall(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
 }
}
```

Component from where you want to call observable to inform another component that button is clicked

```
import { CallService } from "../../../services/call.service";
 
export class MarketplaceComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(public Util: CallService) {
 
  }
 
  buttonClickedToCallObservable() {
   this.Util.sendClickCall('Sending message to another comp that button is clicked');
  }
}
```

Component where you want to perform action on button clicked on another component

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { CallService } from "../../../services/call.service";


ngOnInit() {

 this.subscription = this.Util.getClickCall().subscribe(message => {

 this.message = message;

 console.log('---button clicked at another component---');

 //call you action which need to execute in this component on button clicked

 });

}

import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { CallService } from "../../../services/call.service";
 
 
ngOnInit() {
 
 this.subscription = this.Util.getClickCall().subscribe(message => {
 
 this.message = message;
 
 console.log('---button clicked at another component---');
 
 //call you action which need to execute in this component on button clicked
 
});
 
}
```

My understanding clear on components communication by reading this: https://musttoknows.com/angular-4-angular-5-communicate-two-components-using-observable-subject/

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the simple solution> i tried it in stackblitz which worked fine. But my application has lazy loaded routes (have used providedin: 'root') and HTTP calls to set and get. Could you help me with HTTP calls. tried a lot but not working:

Answer (score 2):

**[This is not what you exactly want but for sure will help you out](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPb0eHXPke41zSa9IBdS?p=preview)**

***I'm surprised there's not more information out there about component communication*** <=>
**[consider this tutorial by angualr2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)**

For sibling components communication, I'd suggest to go with `sharedService`. There are also other options available though.

```
import {Component,bind} from 'angular2/core';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {NameService} from 'src/nameService';


import {TheContent} from 'src/content';
import {Navbar} from 'src/nav';


@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  directives: [TheContent,Navbar],
  providers: [NameService],
  template: '<navbar></navbar><thecontent></thecontent>'
})


export class App {
  constructor() {
    console.log('App started');
  }
}

bootstrap(App,[]);
```

Please refer to link at top for more code.

**Edit:** This is a very small demo. You have already mention that you have already tried with `sharedService`. So please **[consider this tutorial by angualr2](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)** for more information.

Answer (score 2):

**Behaviour subjects.** I wrote a [blog](https://josuevalrob.com/send-variable-between-siblings) about that.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
private noId = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0); 
  defaultId = this.noId.asObservable();

newId(urlId) {
 this.noId.next(urlId); 
 }
```

In this example i am declaring a noid behavior subject of type number. Also it is an observable. And if "something happend" this will change with the new(){} function.

So, in the sibling's components, one will call the function, to make the change, and the other one will be affected by that change, or vice-versa.

For example, I get the id from the URL and update the noid from the behavior subject.

```
public getId () {
  const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); 
  return id; 
}

ngOnInit(): void { 
 const id = +this.getId ();
 this.taskService.newId(id) 
}
```

And from the other side, I can ask if that ID is "what ever i want" and make a choice after that, in my case if i want to delte a task, and that task is the current url, it have to redirect me to the home:

```
delete(task: Task): void { 
  //we save the id , cuz after the delete function, we  gonna lose it 
  const oldId = task.id; 
  this.taskService.deleteTask(task) 
      .subscribe(task => { //we call the defaultId function from task.service.
        this.taskService.defaultId //here we are subscribed to the urlId, which give us the id from the view task 
                 .subscribe(urlId => {
            this.urlId = urlId ;
                  if (oldId == urlId ) { 
                // Location.call('/home'); 
                this.router.navigate(['/home']); 
              } 
          }) 
    }) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One neat way of doing sibling to sibling communication is by using the **@Output decorator** in one child, and a **template reference variable** on the other child to let the parent **invoke this child's methods**. It's extremely similar to using @Ouput for child-parent-communication.

Doing `this.emitSomething.emit(something);` in **child-2** will trigger `onEmitSomething()` in **child-1**.

***child-1.component.ts***

```
onEmitSomething(event: any): void {
  // do something
}
```

***child-2.component.ts***

```
@Output() emitSomething: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

***parent.component.html***

```html
<child-1 #child1></child-1>
<child-2 (emitSomething)="child1.onEmitSomething($event)"></child-2>
```

The two different ways of component interaction can be found here [Angular - Component Interaction](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event)

Answer (score 0):

I have been passing down setter methods from the parent to one of its children through a binding, calling that method with the data from the child component, meaning that the parent component is updated and can then update its second child component with the new data. It does require binding 'this' or using an arrow function though.

This has the benefit that the children aren't so coupled to each other as they don't need a specific shared service.

I am not entirely sure that this is best practice, would be interesting to hear others views on this.

Answer (score 0):

I also like to do the communication between 2 siblings via a parent component via input and output.  it handles OnPush change notification better than using a common service.
Or just use NgRx Store.

Example.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'parent',
    template: `<div><notes-grid 
            [Notes]="(NotesList$ | async)"
            (selectedNote)="ReceiveSelectedNote($event)"
        </notes-grid>
        <note-edit 
            [gridSelectedNote]="(SelectedNote$ | async)"
        </note-edit></div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss']
})
export class ParentComponent {

    // create empty observable
    NotesList$: Observable<Note[]> = of<Note[]>([]);
    SelectedNote$: Observable<Note> = of<Note>();

    //passed from note-grid for selected note to edit.
    ReceiveSelectedNote(selectedNote: Note) {
    if (selectedNote !== null) {
        // change value direct subscribers or async pipe subscribers will get new value.
        this.SelectedNote$ = of<Note>(selectedNote);
    }
    }
    //used in subscribe next() to http call response.  Left out all that code for brevity.  This just shows how observable is populated.
    onNextData(n: Note[]): void {
    // Assign to Obeservable direct subscribers or async pipe subscribers will get new value.
    this.NotesList$ = of<Note[]>(n.NoteList);  //json from server
    }
}

//child 1 sibling
@Component({
  selector: 'note-edit',
  templateUrl: './note-edit.component.html', // just a textarea for noteText and submit and cancel buttons.
  styleUrls: ['./note-edit.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class NoteEditComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() gridSelectedNote: Note;

    constructor() {
    }

// used to capture @Input changes for new gridSelectedNote input
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
     if (changes.gridSelectedNote && changes.gridSelectedNote.currentValue !== null) {      
      this.noteText = changes.gridSelectedNote.currentValue.noteText;
      this.noteCreateDtm = changes.gridSelectedNote.currentValue.noteCreateDtm;
      this.noteAuthorName = changes.gridSelectedNote.currentValue.noteAuthorName;
      }
  }

}

//child 2 sibling

@Component({
    selector: 'notes-grid',
    templateUrl: './notes-grid.component.html',  //just an html table with notetext, author, date
    styleUrls: ['./notes-grid.component.scss'],
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class NotesGridComponent {

// the not currently selected fromt eh grid.
    CurrentSelectedNoteData: Note;

    // list for grid
    @Input() Notes: Note[];

    // selected note of grid sent out to the parent to send to sibling.
    @Output() readonly selectedNote: EventEmitter<Note> = new EventEmitter<Note>();

    constructor() {
    }

    // use when you need to send out the selected note to note-edit via parent using output-> input .
    EmitSelectedNote(){
    this.selectedNote.emit(this.CurrentSelectedNoteData);
    }

}


// here just so you can see what it looks like.

export interface Note {
    noteText: string;
    noteCreateDtm: string;
    noteAuthorName: string;
}
```