# Adding multiple HTML Blocks in a single html file using angular2 and using their elements between each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular2-template

Assume I have a template.html, and 2 sub-templates (sub-template1.html & sub-template2.html), how do i get them to render in template.html, and also use the classes and ID, and other DOM related variables from sub-template1.html in sub-template2.html.

for eg: sub-template1.html has a video, and I need to access it's current time in sub-template2.html

```
<!--template.html-->
<html>
<head>
<title></title
</head>
<body>
<!--- sub-template1.html -->
<br>
<!--- sub-template2.html -->
</body>
</html>


<!-- sub-template1.html -->
<div>
<video></video>
</div>


<!-- sub-template2.html -->
<div>
<h1> <!-- current time from video in sub-template1.html --></h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an service to pass the data between two controllers. Please refer the below link

[Angular 2 Sibling Component Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication)