# Angular4 passing information between components

Tags: angular, callback, routes, components

My App has a Header section and body section, I am using routes so that the body section can navigate between pages, while the header is always there.

The data for the header comes from two services `productService.getProducts()` and `priceService.getPrices()` which is able to be modified on two of the pages `productService.addProduct(produceID)`, `productService.removeProduct(productID)`.

The data in the services is updating correctly, but I need a way to tell the header to call `getProducts()` and `getPrices()` again.

I thought I could have a callback from the pages, but it seems you cannot include a callback in a route?

Comment: You might need to fire an event when the data gets updated in the service, so that header could listen (subscribe) when that happens.

Comment: I agree with @Nugu are you using/understand observable(s)? It seems like a solid use case for a state tree using redux, if you don't already have one. Look into the Redux pattern.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668262/2708210

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a `Subject` in your service and subscribe to it in your header's component. Every time you update data in service, just call `Subject.next()`.

```
subject: Subject<string> = new Subject();

updateData() {
  // your own logic
  this.subject.next();
}
```

Then you can do what you want(such as call some other functions) at `Subject.subscribe()`.

```
product$ = this.service.subject;   // Subject defined at your service

constructor() {
  this.product$.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('product data has been updated!');
  });
}
```

Also, If you just want to get the newest data, you can just transform updated data via `subject.next(newestData)`, and then you can get what you want at `subject.subscribe()`.

refer this simple **[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/PVHUL3etoOzs0ojsJndV?p=preview)**.

Comment: Adding to this excellent answer, remmeber to `unsubscribe` your subject when view is destroyed.

Comment: @Faisal thanks for notation about **unsubscribe**, this can prevent from memory leak problem.  But it maybe unnecessary for OP's specific requirement for `Header` is always displayed.

Answer (score 2):

I think in order to solve your problem more efficiently you need to consider of using [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) this way you can subscribe for a store in your header and then on related action gets fired you can run `do stuff` in your header.

It might be looking something like

1. Dispatch an action that mutate the store
   `this.store.dispatch(new yourthing.SomeAction());`
2. Subscribe for a change: 

   `this.store.select(fromYourThing.getYourThing)
         .subscribe((thing) => {
            // do stuff
         });
       });`

For more details on `ngrx` check these links:

https://blog.angular.io/announcing-ngrx-4-87df0eaa2806
https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5
https://blog.nrwl.io/using-ngrx-4-to-manage-state-in-angular-applications-64e7a1f84b7b

Also run this [example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app) locally so you can see how it all goes in action.