# can we access a variable in one child component from another child component?

Tags: angular

I have a Child component which call and gets a Http get response. Now, I want the same response to get displayed on another child component. Can there be a way to access a variable from one child component to another in Angular?

Comment: same response to be used in 2 different child's then created a shared service to get data .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 Sibling Component Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication)