# Angular 8 - Copy select value in another component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, components

I'm learning Angular, i need to pass a select value to a "p" in another component. So when the value of the select changes the "p" element also changes.

**app.component.html**

```html
<navbar></navbar>
<todo-list-cards></todo-list-cards>
<test></test>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**todo.component.html**

```html
<div class="contenedorTareas">
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" id="cards" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                content.</p>
            <select name="selector" id="selector">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Header</div>
            <div class="card-body">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**test.component.html**

```html
<p><!-- Here the value of the <select> should be--></p>
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about the relationship between the `todo` and `test` components. Is it parent-child, siblings, other.. ?

Comment: They are siblings

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 Sibling Component Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication)

Answer (score 0):

Best in my opinion is to bind the selected value and the paragraph content using a service. 
Try adding todo.service.ts with the following:

```
private selected: string;
public get selectedValue() {
    return this.selected;
  }
public setSelectedValue(value: string){
    this.selected = value;
}
```

Then, in todo update the value in the service,
and in test simply get it into the

:

```
<p>{{todoService.SelectedValue}}</p>
```

Comment: todo  can use the select action to update the service 

todoService.setSelectedValue(selectedValue);

Answer (score 0):

**test.component.ts (child component)**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',

})

export Class TestComponent {

@Input() selectedOption: string;

}
```

Now use that input in your html file.

**test.component.html**

```
<p>{{selectedOption}}</p>
```

When you include your test component in a parent component i.e. todo.component.html
you can pass input selectedOption from parent to child as [input] in html tag

```
<div class="contenedorTareas">
    <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" id="cards" style="max-width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-header">Header</div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Primary card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                content.</p>
            <select [(ngModel)]="optionSelected" name="selector" id="selector">
                <option>Option 1</option>
                <option>Option 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cards">
        <div class="card text-white bg-primary mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
            <div class="card-header">Header</div>
            <div class="card-body">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>

  <app-test [selectedOption]="optionSelected"></app-test>
```

**todo.component.ts**  parent component

```
export class TodoComponent {

optionSelected: string;
}
```