# How to access input value in multiple component?

Tags: angular

I have 2 components :  headerComponent and searchPageComponent.
    Whatever the value we enter on header component search bar, the search page component should get the value.

*header.component.html*

```
<form class="form-inline md-form form-sm">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sm mr-3 w-75" id="searchString" type="text" 
             placeholder="Search" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" name="searchString" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
          <button class="headerSearchbarBtn" id="btnSearch" routerLink="/searchResult">
              <span class="headerSearchbarIcon"></span>
           </button>
       </form>
```

*header.component.ts*

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
        searchValue: string;
        constructor(private router: Router) { }
        ngOnInit() {
         }
         onChange($event) {
          this.searchValue = $event;
         }
       }
```

*Search.component.ts*

```
export class SearchComponent implements  OnInit {
        ngOnInit() {
          console.log(this.searchValue); // 'this.searchValue' => value should come from header.compomnent.ts 
        }
      }
```

There is no parent child relation here, I want to know how the data is passed from one component to other,
    and Why cant we directly access the input field box value in different components in Angular?

Comment: check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884451/angular-2-sibling-component-communication

Answer (score 1):

Service in add this code

```
 setSearchValue = new Subject<any>();
  getSearchValue = this.setSearchValue.asObservable();
```

First import your Service in Header component

```
constructor(private service: HeaderService)
```

```
header.component.ts
```

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
        searchValue: string;
        constructor(private router: Router) { }
        ngOnInit() {
         }
         onChange($event) {
           this.service.setSearchValue.next(event);
           });
         }
       }
```

```
Search.component.ts
```

```
export class SearchComponent implements  OnInit {
        ngOnInit() {
         this.getSearchValue();
        }
      }

   getSearchValue(){
      this.service.getSearchValue.subscribe((value) => {
       this.searchValue = value;
      });
    }
```

Comment: This works, But subscibe is not returning the value for the first time(it is not updating value - this.searchValue = value;), if I again enter some value on the input field, then only it is returning value.

Comment: @PavanRT Please add code in stackblitz  and share link.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Fuser.service.ts

Comment: I have updated the code here - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-getinputvalue - @Vijay Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

You need to use BehaviorSubject for without parent and child relation components.
This link will help to you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-behaviorsubject-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fone%2Fone.component.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service and a subject to communicate between sibling components

```
export class SharedService {

    private searchInputSource = new Subject<string>();

    searchInput = this.searchInputSource.asObservable();

    setSearchInput(value: string) {
        this.searchInput.next(value);
    }
}
```

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
    searchInput: string;
    constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    onChange($event) {
        this.sharedService.setSearchInput.next($event);
    });
}
```

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    privates subscription: Subscription;
    searchInput: string;

    ngOnInit(private sharedService: SharedService) {
        this.subscription = sharedService.searchInput.subscribe(
            value => {
                this.searchInput = value;
            });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```