# Child component not getting value from parent

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

In my application I have one parent component and some child components. Need to implement child parent communication here.

1. On click child1Component need to pass some data from child1Component to child2Component.
2. Display that data in child2Component.

What I did:-

1. Emitted values from child1 to parent and tried to bind/pass the same value from  parent to child2.
2. But am not getting the value in ngOnInit of child2 as shown below. Need to display that data in child2.
3. Also the navigation to child2 is not working always redirecting to login page just after displaying the child2 for 1 or 2 seconds.

   ```
              Child1:

              <div (click)="onClickData(data)"></div>

              @Output() getData = new EventEmitter();

               onClickData (data:any) {
               this.getData.emit(data);
             }

             Child2:

             @Input() clickedItem: any = '';

             ngOnInit() {
               alert(this.clickedItem)
             }

             Parent:

             <app-child1
               (getdata)="getDataEvent($event)"
             >
             </app-child1>

             <app-child2
              [clickedItem] = "clickedData"
             >
             </app-child2>

             clickedData:any;

             getDataEvent($event: any) {
               this.clickedData = $event;
               this.router.navigate(['child2'])
             }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

`ngOnInit` will work only while initiating the component. Please use the `ngOnChanges` life cycle hook

Child2:

```
      @Input() clickedItem: any = '';

      ngOnChanges() {
        alert(this.clickedItem)
      }
```

Comment: thank you so much for the reply let me try this, also i have updated the question with one more issue about the navigation!

Comment: is child 2 is used in child2 route also?

Comment: i tried ngOnchanges but the method is not executing, i cannot see an alert message. I could see one blank alert message when it was ngoninit!

Comment: No, child one and two has two separate routes

Comment: is child 1 and 2 are used in same page or different page?

Comment: same page, Child one and Child2 are sibling components, both siblings comes under one parent component .Both are loaded in the parent component's view.

Comment: `this.router.navigate(['child2'])` here  are we again routing to child 2 component with a route url child2? Where are you expecting to display the alert?

Comment: I need to display data passed from child 1  in child2 component

Comment: ngOnChanges will execute when ever there is a change in @Input() variables of your component. Did you implement the OnChanges Interface in your child 2 class?

Comment: yes implemented, "implements OnInit, OnChanges  {"

Comment: `this.getData.emit(data);` here what is the data you are passing? suppose if data = 'abc' and if you are passing same 'abc' as data in every click then it will not work because the data is not changing. In each click you have to pass different data. If you pass an object or array as data also will work. Please try this.

Comment: Oh! yes!, am passing same string value on every click.. am getting data in parent on first emit from child 1. From the parent am trying to bind the same value to child 2  but not working.. let me try using object/array! and i will get back! Thanks!

Comment: Actually there is no multiple click, there is only one click in child 1 but trying to pass same data to next sibling component via parent! and data is a string! i tried using array but nothing worked!

Comment: You can use `@ViewChild(Child2Component) child2: Child2Component` In the parent.
And when ever you click set `child2.clickedItem = event;`

Answer (score 2):

if you want to transfer data between two sibling components, you better use a service.
see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018798/11952668

Comment: yes , i came to know that we can use service/subject to pass data between sibling components. But i would like to check whether this way of passing is possible or not..it was working for me once..in my old projects.

Comment: may i know, this way of communication is possible right? we can do this if we need to transfer a small bit of data.