# how to achieve onclick in one component(html) and functionality for that called from another component in Angular 6

Tags: typescript, angular6

A tag (instead of buttons) is in one component (i.e. pages/comp/HTML). The respective function (click) should be called from another component (i.e shared/comp/ts)

Comment: I think you mean achieve. See here: https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between component in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501577/how-to-communicate-between-component-in-angular)