# Transfer value from separated components in Angular

Tags: angular

I have 2 components. Component A and B. Component B has a value that I am trying to rereive in component A. Component B lies in a different folder to A. How can I send the value to A without using something like localStorage.

Here is my code for context.

Compononent B

```
@Input() offerExpiry: any;

  async ngOnInit() {
    this._loader.start();
    if (this._exploreService.offer) {
        ...
    } else {
      const offer = await this._exploreService.getOfferDetails();
      //value I need is 'this.offerExpiry'
      this.offerExpiry = offer.expiryDate;
    }
    this._loader.stop();
  }
```

Compononent A

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-offer-subheader',
  templateUrl: './offer-subheader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./offer-subheader.component.scss']
})
export class OfferSubheaderComponent {

  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() active: string;
  @Output() back = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() offerExpiry: any;

  onBack() {
    this.back.emit();
  }

}
```

I am trying to use Input, Output but am not having any success

Comment: check this (possible duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/q/30501577/2050306

Comment: Yes thanks, my one is duplicated. Will close.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate between component in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501577/how-to-communicate-between-component-in-angular)

Comment: you can check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydxhki - as of now im passing true from child to parrent. use the service if both are in same level(not parent and child).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in 2 ways:

1. You need create more one Parent component or using your app
   component, component B has @Output() and component A @Input(). You
   subscribe to component B @Output changes and set value to Parent
   component, and pass it on input of your component A.
2. Create a service like this:

   export class ExchangeService {
         private value$: BehaviorSubject = new BehaviorSubject(1);

   ```
     get value() {
       return this.value$.asObservable();
     }

     updateValue(value: number) {
       this.value$.next(value);
     }
   }
   ```

And inject it in both your components and enjoy your data managing)