# *ngFor no updating list on router-outlet

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have this structure on appComponent:

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

on the `<router-outlet>` ,my main component('/'), is the `Home-component`.

I have a **table** in `Home-component`

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3" *ngFor="let stock of stocks">
```

and I want to change the table regarding my selector in the Header.

```
<select class="input-select" [(ngModel)]="familyProductSelected" (change)="onChange()" 
                             [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [value]="familyProductSelected">
```

I have an `onChange()` method. This method is called from `header` referencing a `Home Component` method.

```
onChange() {
 this.homeComponent.loadProduct(this.familyProductSelected);
}
```

This method, which is updating the `stocks` list is working fine, and the array is updated correctly, but the view is not updating it.

I tried with `this.stocks = [...this.stocks];`, `trackBy`, `this.stocks= Object.assign({}, this.stocks);` and with `ChangeDetectorRef`. non of these worked for me. On the last one, I'm getting `NullInjectorError`

```
main.ts:13 NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HomeComponent -> HeaderComponent]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HomeComponent -> HeaderComponent]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for HeaderComponent!
```

How can I fix this?
This is my first question for Angular, please let me know if I need to add more information.

Comment: `this.homeComponent.loadProduct(this.familyProductSelected)` how did you initialise homeComponent in header component?

Comment: Is there a Module that declare HeaderComponent ? Is there a module that Declare HomeComponent and import HeaderModule ?

Comment: @Kshitij I do it on the costructor of header.component.ts 
public homeComponent: HomeComponent,

Comment: @Marco yes. the only thing that is not working is the view of the table in "Home-component". Even though the List "stocks" is being updated I can't see the changes in the view.

Comment: Could you put your code to Stackblitz? So that we can take a look. @Clams

Comment: @Kshitij https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhmgkc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @Kshitij https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yhmgkc?file=src/app/home/home.component.ts

you can check at home-component (Table at ln39), Header-Component onChange method (ln 143) "loadProduct" method in Home-Component (at ln 32)

Comment: `providers: [HomeComponent,AppComponent]` should be `exports: [HomeComponent,AppComponent]` as they are not services. I couldn't run your code as there are few missing files

Comment: if I don't declare it as providers I have an error. NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[HeaderComponent -> HomeComponent]:

if you need to run the code I would need to give you the front-end, backend(java spring project)  and database(MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

Import HeaderComponent in your `app.module.ts` & then in the import array in @ngModule
Add below **bold** code into your `app.module.ts`

`**import { HeaderComponent} from 'your_path_to_componenet'**;`

`@NgModule({ declarations: [**HeaderComponent**] })`
`export class AppModule{ }`

`NullInjectorError` will resolve & your code should work fine

Comment: The nullInjectorError is when I try to add ChangeDetectorRef on Home-Component.

without the ChangeDetectorRef, all the code is working fine, the list is updating correctly, but the view (table in the HTML) is not updating.

on my app.module.ts I have all the components added to @NgModule declarations already

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Service approach to send data between components, which is explained in the following post:

[How to communicate between component in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30501577/how-to-communicate-between-component-in-angular/36019070)

And if you want to re-render the view for your HomeComponent manually, use [ChangeDetectorRef](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef)

Comment: The problem is not with the methods, but with the re-render as you state. but when I try to use ChangeDetectorRef, as I explain at the end of the post, I'm getting an error NullInjectorError, I guess this is because Home-component belong to <router-outlet>

Comment: You could try calling the ChangeDetectorRef method as in the HomeComponent after finishing the statement, as in your AppComponent as a validation test. Maybe, creating a utils method that contains the ChangeDetectorRef in order to achieve DRY. Also try to use another approach.